# Assign symbol (function) address to function pointer Boost dll module.

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, function-pointers

I am trying to get function addresses from a shared library using boost dll/shared_library module and assign them to function pointers to use in my program, but the loaded function addresses are incorrect and result in segmentation fault when used in the program. The shared library contains correct symbol addresses as I can load and use the symbol correctly directly with `dlsym()`. Below is the code I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dll/shared_library.hpp>
namespace dll = boost::dll;

int (*add)(int a, int b);

int main ()
{
  try
    {
      dll::shared_library lib ("utils.so");

      add = lib.get <typeof(add)> ("add");
    }
  catch (...)
    {
      std::cout << "Failed to load library" << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Can someone please suggest what I am missing here and the correct way to load API functions from shared libs using BOOST. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Wrong results when running? Crashes? Something else? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I did mention "but the loaded function addresses are incorrect and result in segmentation fault when used in the program" in the question description.

Comment: And what is the value of `add`? What is it pointing at? It's not a null pointer? Have you tried to debug your program?

Comment: How do you know the library was loaded successfully?  Don't you need to do `if (lib) {`?

Comment: GDB Debug session: https://pastebin.com/SkqZuRTW

Comment: And where is the problem (the segfault you mentioned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `shared_library::get<T>`, `T` should be a function type, not a pointer to function.

```
add = lib.get <int (int a, int b)>("add");
```

Comment: I have a large API header for this shared lib that I would like to pull in and assign it to function pointers. This is what I have been doing with dlsym:
https://pastebin.com/NdzqUAsC

I have a macro that pulls in the API automatically in my main program. Can this be achieved with BOOST as well ?

Comment: Use `typeof(*add)` or even better `decltype(*add)`.